# Swift, Accessing data for a table view

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, closures

So, I load my firebase node, and then append the data into an array to use in a table view, but for some reason i cannot access the data inside of planitTitles, unless i am within this closure. Please, any workaround ? I feel like i have achieved this before. Thanks

```
func loadFirebase(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let planits = ref.child("planits")

    planits.observe( .value, with: { (planitsSnapshot) in

                for child in planitsSnapshot.children {
                    let planSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                    let planDict = planSnap.value as! [String: Any]

                if self.keyForThisPlanit.contains(planSnap.key){

                     let title = planDict["Planit Title"] as! String

                    self.planitTitles.append(title)

                        }
            }
        })
    print(self.planitTitles)

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendUpdatesCell") as? ViewUpdatesTVCell else { return UITableViewCell() }


   cell.randomPlanitNumber.text = planitTitles[indexPath.row]
// CRASHES HERE WITH ERROR OUT OF INDEX
    return cell

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload the table after the for loop

```
var planitTitles = [String]()
```

//

```
func loadFirebase(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let planits = ref.child("planits")

    planits.observe( .value, with: { (planitsSnapshot) in
                self.planitTitles.removeAll() // you may want to clear here to avoid duplications 
                for child in planitsSnapshot.children {
                    let planSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                    let planDict = planSnap.value as! [String: Any]                  
                    if self.keyForThisPlanit.contains(planSnap.key){
                        let title = planDict["Planit Title"] as! String
                           self.planitTitles.append(title)

                     }
                  }
             print(self.planitTitles)
             self.tableView.reloadData()
      })

}
func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return planitTitles.count // to prevent cellForRowAt indexOutOfBounds crash
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Overlooked the reload data part. rookie mistake. thanks